# How send and received string, array and hash in perl function

Tags: perl

I have like this situation.

```
my %ha = ()
my @ar = ('1','2')
my $st = 't'

f(%ha,@ar,$st);

sub f
{

my (%h, @a,$s) = @_;
```

OR

```
   my %h = shift;
   my @a shift;
   my $s = shift;
}
```

both do not work. What can I do?

Comment: Please read https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub for more information about calling subroutines and parsing parameters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot pass complicated data structures as arguments - they get unpacked into lists of values, and your subroutine can't tell where the boundaries are.

What you can do is pass references instead:

```
my %hash = ()
my @arr = ('123','456')
my $str = 'test'

sub func
{
   my ( $hashref, $arrayref, $str ) = @_; 
   my %copy_of_hash = %$hashref;
   my @copy_of_array = @$arrayref;

   ## or you can do it by following the reference to modify the hash without copying it:
   $hashref->{'key'} = "value"; 
}


func ( \%hash, \@arr, $str );
```

Comment: Nit: One can *pass references*. *Passing by reference* means something else (and Perl always passes by reference).

Answer (score 0):

From https://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut

[ ITEMS ] makes a new, anonymous array, and returns a reference to that array. { ITEMS } makes a new, anonymous hash, and returns a reference to that hash.

```
$aref = [ 1, "foo", undef, 13 ];
# $aref now holds a reference to an array

$href = { APR => 4, AUG => 8 };
# $href now holds a reference to a hash
```

So you can do the creation and referencing in a single step. I find this to be simpler and clearer than the backslash way.